# Navbar Links Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I have been experiencing a strange glitch where my navbar, when clicked does not take the user anywhere despite there being a valid  tag.

My site is located at http://www.tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/rising/.

Comment: showing errors in the console.Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely blocking all your `scroll` anchors, and not only those that have href value set to a hash:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1200);
});
```

Remove the `scroll` class from them (or modify the code above) and they will work normally.